# How to include spouse for Portugal D7 visa?

Tags: visa, residency, dependent-visa, portugal

When applying for the [D7 visa for Portugal](https://www.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/portugal/usa/english/), how does the applicant include their spouse in the application (as a dependent)? The [visa application form](https://vistos.mne.gov.pt/images/schengen/formularios/application_form_en_092021.pdf) does not have a field to include a spouse as a dependent applicant. If the dependent applicant fills out the same form, there is also not a field to indicate that the form is for a dependent applicant.

Comment: The D7 visa is for residency rather than travel. Believe that this question would be better suited for SE Expatriates.

Comment: Do note that the application form you link above is the form for short stays; for residents permits like the D7 visa, you will need to use and follow the instructions for a "national visa".

Comment: The page that you've linked under the text "D7 visa for Portugal" does not contain "D7," and the D visa section in the drop-down list contains only six entries, so after looking at that page I am left with no idea what a D7 visa is.  Can you link to a page that actually explains what it is?

Comment: @phoog Official resources in English seem to be scant — it may be "fixed residency" on the [official site](https://vistos.mne.gov.pt/en/national-visas/general-information/type-of-visa#fixed-residency) — but the [D7 visa](https://www.sovereigngroup.com/portugal/private-clients/residency-in-portugal/portugal-passive-income-d7-visa/) reportedly "provides residency status to non-EU / EEA / Swiss citizens, including retirees, who intend to relocate to Portugal and are in receipt of a reasonable and regular passive income."

Comment: @phoog You are right, the webpage does not explicitly use the term "D7" (D7 is really just the type called "Due to Retirement..." from the dropdown menu). I could not find an English webpage from the Portuguese authorities with more detailed information about D7. [Here](https://www.portuguese-nationality.com/residency/the-d7-visa-portugal) is a third-party page with more information.

Comment: @mlc May I know which instructions you refer to? I did follow the instructions for a national visa to reach the application form linked.